# How to invoke a webservice with holders as parameters in jax-ws

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am new to jax-ws development and I have generated java source files from a wsdl using wsimport.
And I need to call a function from one of these source files into my UI program.

The function I need to call looks like:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "GetX")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "GetX", targetNamespace = "urn:Control", className = "jaxws.control.GetX")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "GetXResponse", targetNamespace = "urn:Control", className = "jaxws.control.GetXResponse")
public void myHostGetX(
    @WebParam(name = "isActive", targetNamespace = "", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
    Holder<Boolean> Active);
```

Lets say the this funtion is part of a class called Class A.

But if I try invoking this by doing something like,

```
boolean foo;
ResponseFromWS response = myHostGetX(foo);
```

I get an error like,

`The method myHostGetX(Holder<Boolean>) in the type Class A is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)`

How can I call this `Holder<Boolean>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the **value** of the holder.
So either:

```
myHostGetX(new Holder(Boolean.TRUE)); //note plain boolean should work in the constructor.
```

OR

```
myHostGetX(new Holder());
```

OR

```
Holder holder = new Holder();
holder.value = Boolean.TRUE;
myHostGetX(holder)
```

Any of those should work.
It's worth mentioning that since this is an OUTPUT parameter, the setting of the value should occur within the implementation of that method.